# Text and code blocks under spoiler

Tags: support, bug, code-formatting, formatting, spoilers

I'm trying to ask a question and put additional information under the spoiler. The best solution I've found looks like this:

```
>!Text block
>!
>!<pre><code>
>!code block
>!</code></pre>
>!
>!Text block
>!
>!<pre><code>
>!code block
>!</code></pre>
>!
>!Text block
```

Which results in:

> Text block
>
> ```
> code block
> ```
>
> Text block
>
> ```
> code block
> ```
>
> Text block

Is it a bug? How can I hide the second and third "Text block"?

Comment: *"and put additional information under the spoiler"* - I can't think of _any_ good reason to do this.

Comment: Also see: [Spoilers don't support block formatting (and so don't format well)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-support-block-formatting-and-so-dont-format-well), been broken for 10 years.

Comment: I've changed spoiler with quote to shade the additional block. Thanks, to the link with example of formatted blocks inside quote!